# WriteProcessMemory to memcpy

Tags: c++, memory-management

I would like to convert my hooking method, to a more effient way. My current code uses WriteProcessMemory() with GetCurrentProcess(), which is totally useless. I think a simple memcpy can easily do the same thing. Here's what I tried to do:

```
DWORD dwAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(lpModule, lpFuncName);
BYTE jmp[6] = { 0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3 };

memcpy((LPVOID)dwAddr, &jmp[0], 6);
//WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)dwAddr, jmp, 6, 0);
```

The WriteProcessMemory API works perfectly, but with my custom memcpy, it isn't working. Could anyone tell me where did I fail?

Comment: Too broad- "isn't working" is a useless problem descriptor.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. In my case "isn't working" means, that the bytes aren't copied to dwAddr.

Comment: What, that's it? They're the same bytes afterwards? The app crashes with an error? What, exactly, happens?

Comment: It isn't crashing, the bytes are simply the same as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `WriteProcessMemory()` is to write to *another process' virtual memory*. You don't need it to edit your own process virtual memory.

You must howover make sure you have right to modify data in that particular address. Even though the memory is yours, it might be read-only and the system kernel enforces that.

Use `VirtualProtect()` to change permissions on the memory space you are trying to modify.

Also, note you are destroying the original function code when you overwrite data in that address. **This is NOT how to hook Windows APIs.**

If it intersts you, I have [this function that hooks APIs](https://gist.github.com/Havenard/aa2ee90b14304466eeb3). It replaces the original function pointer by yours in the PE table while returning the original one so you can use later. Unfortunately its outdated and should work only for 32-bits.

Comment: Is it automatically checked within the WriteProcessMemory API? Since it's working with it. I understand, that there's a chance, that it's not writable, but in the current case I'm sure that the memory space is writable.

Comment: @user It for sure won't be writable since it's code

Comment: Well, okay. You're right. I'm trying to add VirtualProtect before copying.

Comment: @Havenard I'm not destroying the original function. I store it, and also I've got some other code, which wasn't necessary to write here.

Comment: Sorry, it really was my fault. I couldn't make sure that the memory region is writable. After adding VirtualProtect, it worked perfectly. Sorry guys & thank you!

Comment: @Havenard The hooking is fine so long as you don't need a trampoline.

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem at all to use `memcpy` here. However, you will need to use `VirtualProtect` to change the protection flags for the destination to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. Restore the original protection when you've finished writing.

If you are targeting x86/x64 that's all you need to do. For other architectures you need a call to `FlushInstructionCache`.

It is also a mistake to store a pointer to a `DWORD`. Don't cast the return value of `GetProcAddress`. It is a pointer.

Comment: Of course, I just realized that both answers are valid. The OP wasn't anywhere near clear enough with "isn't working".

Comment: I'm targeting x86/x64 only. A small question:
If it fails, for example because I didn't set VirtualProtect, then why isn't it failing with WriteProcess too? Is it automatically check inside the WriteProcess API?

Comment: WriteProcess maps the memory (as writeable, obviously) and then writes to the memory inside the kernel. Which does the same as VirtualProtect does.

Comment: WriteProcessMemory is modifying the protection flags. I guess.

Comment: Sorry, it really was my fault. I couldn't make sure that the memory region is writable. After adding VirtualProtect, it worked perfectly. Sorry guys & thank you!

Comment: Why are you casting to DWORD?